# Regex in removing a special character pattern

Tags: python, regex

Now I got a string in the pandas dataframe like this

```
"[""www.abccc.com"]"", "[""www.gsfa.com"]""
```

So What I want to do is to replace the "["" and "]"" with '' with regex

I tried a couple of combination to first grab the pattern e.g:

```
r' \["[""] '
r' [\"[""] '
r' [\"[\""] '
```

All are not working ...
and when I use the following in regex101:

```
[\"[\"\"]
```

I got 4 matches for each single special character, instead of matching all patterns in once.

Can anyone let me know, how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
recheck = re.compile(r'\"[\[\]]\"\"')
print(recheck.sub(' ', r'"[""www.abccc.com"]"", "[""www.gsfa.com"]""'))
```

should work, it'll match the ", then either [ or ], then two "".

the brackets denote which characters the re should check against, so [""] ends up matching a single double-quote, while ["'] will match either single quotes or double quotes for one character. that's why my re matches the left or right bracket within the three double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^]]+')

some_junky_string = '"[""www.abccc.com"]"", "[""www.gsfa.com"]""'
content = [m.group(0).strip('"') for m in rx.finditer(some_junky_string)]
print(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is just remove the `[""` and the `]""` so that the remaining is only the quotes.

```
import re
regex = r'(\[\"\"|\]\"\")'
data = r'"[""www.abccc.com"]"", "[""www.gsfa.com"]""'
print(re.sub(regex, '', data))
```

This gives:

```
"www.abccc.com", "www.gsfa.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using pandas, so you need

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'"*\["*|"*]"*', '"')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/qtq8vg/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "*                       '"' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "*                       '"' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "*                       '"' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "*                       '"' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
```

Answer (score 0):

Substituting matches from `r'(\"\[\"|\"\]\")'` with an empty string (`''`) gives the output you're looking for.

The pattern makes use of a capture group that matches on:

- The leading `"["` at the start of the string
- The trailing `"]"` towards the end of the string

Passing this as the first argument in `re.sub(pattern, substitution, string)` with an empty string as the second argument and the string you want to manipulate as the third will result in the replacement of the above defined matches with empty strings - leaving you with just `"` at both the start and end of the resultant string as per your original question.

Full example below.

```py
import re

result = re.sub(r'(\"\[\"|\"\]\")', '', r'"[""www.abccc.com"]""')
print(result)

output: "www.abccc.com"
```